# Extracting zipped file and saving with different name

Tags: python, zip

I wish to extract an excel file that is within a zip, but change the name of the file when I save it. I believe this can be done without using `os` to rename the file and can be done within `zipfile`. However, when I try the following it does not work

```
import pandas as pd
import zipfile
from urllib.request import urlopen
import io

url = 'https://www.cftc.gov/files/dea/history/fut_disagg_xls_2010.zip'
save_dir = '/home/mydirectory/'
file = zipfile.ZipFile((io.BytesIO(urlopen(url).read())))
file.filename = 'test.xls'
file.extractall(save_dir)
```

It saves, but the file has the old name. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Changing `file.filename = 'test.xls'` will not affect the names of the extracted files. How many Excel files are in your zip file? You can use [ZipFile.namelist](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist) to get a list of files in your zip file. Choose a specific name from that list then use [ZipFile.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open) to get a file-like object you can use to get the decompressed bytes.

Comment: I want to write the file with a new name; how do I do that with Zipfile?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking should have been covered by the various python tutorials.

See the comments in the code below.

```py
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
import shutil
import os

# prepare dummy zip file
data = b'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'

zf = BytesIO()
z = ZipFile(zf, mode='w')
z.writestr('foo.txt', data)
z.writestr('bar.zzz', data[::-1])

print(z.namelist())  # what's in our dummy zip file

# find the first file with extension .txt
interesting = [
    n for n in z.namelist() if os.path.splitext(n)[-1].lower() == '.txt'
][0]

# get a file-like object from which we can read to get the bytes therein
f = z.open(interesting)

# open a file into which to write said bytes
out = BytesIO()
# IRL, replace preceding line with
# out = open('newname.txt', 'wb') # look Ma, I've renamed the file!

# read from f and write to out
shutil.copyfileobj(f, out)

print(out.getvalue())
# IRL, replace preceding line with
# out.close()
```

- [ZipFile.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open)
- [shutil.copyfileobj](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj)